# Have onclick method change into a size with animations

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, onclick

This is probably gonna be a repeat
I just couldn't find anything on here that could help. I want when this is clicked on it won't just snap to that size, I want it to slowly turn into the target size. If this a repeat please let me know! If you can help, please try and explain how it works, that way I can learn quicker if it makes sense.

```
  layoutSmallerButton.setOnClickListener{
        val layoutShrink = linearLayout2.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
        layoutShrink.height = 0
        linearLayout2.layoutParams = layoutShrink

        val buttonSmaller = layoutSmallerButton.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
        buttonSmaller.height = 0
        layoutSmallerButton.layoutParams = buttonSmaller

        val buttonLarger = layoutLargerButton.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
        buttonLarger.height = 50
        layoutLargerButton.layoutParams = buttonLarger

        val internetViewLarger = internetView.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
        internetViewLarger.height = 1700
        internetView.layoutParams = internetViewLarger

    }
```

Thank you! Add any comments to maybe improve my code or anything! Thank you, please don't be rude!

Comment: why not animate its scale from 0 to 1?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation) out.

Here's something you can do:

```
layoutSmallerButton.setOnClickListener{
    animateHeightOfView(layoutShrink, 0)
    animateHeightOfView(buttonSmaller, 0)
    animateHeightOfView(buttonLarger, 50)
    animateHeightOfView(internetViewLarger, 1700)
}

fun animateHeightOfView(view: View, targetHeight: Int, animationDuration: Int = 1000){
    ObjectAnimator.ofInt(view, "height", targetHeight).apply{
        duration = animationDuration
        start()
    }
}
```

Edit: If you are using ConstraintLayout (which is recommended), you can use the [ConstraintSet](https://proandroiddev.com/creating-awesome-animations-using-constraintlayout-and-constraintset-part-i-390cc72c5f75) for animations. It is quite easy to implement and you can preview the whole layout (before and after) in the XML files.

But it requires Android KitKat or newer.

Comment: Hey I'm just now seeing this. Thank you!